# Asus P8P67: How do I install bluetooth drivers on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I have recently reset my Windows 10 install. Now, when I try to install the Bluetooth drivers from the website so I can use my new Bluetooth headphone without requiring a cable, it fails with the error message "Does not support this Operating System: WNT_6.2H_64. My bluetooth is provided by Qualcomm Atheros, but...

1. The drivers from the Asus support website don't work on Win10;
2. The Qualcomm website doesn't have a support page I can find;
3. I found an unofficial driver aggregator for Atheros, but I cannot find the relevant driver in there. I don't even know if they HAVE a relevant driver on there.

Where can I find the most recent drivers for my bluetooth?

Comment: Can you see your Bluetooth adapter in Device Manager?

Comment: @Atoadaso I'm not sure. I got a ton of devices in my manager, but none of them realy stand out as bluetooth or the code that certain websites tell me it is. I do have one device that's referred to as "out of date device", but I'm not sure if that's the one.